# Exclude (ignore) object during serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

Have a ordinary hierarchy of objects that inherit common to all interface or abstract class.

```
public abstract class AActivation
{
    public bool IsActivated
    { get; set; }
}

public class Root : AActivation
{
    public int Value
    { get; set; }

    public List<LevelOne> Childs
    { get; private set; }

    public Root()
    {
        Value = 1000;
        Childs = new List<LevelOne>();
    }
}

public class LevelOne : AActivation
{
    static int _i = 0;

    public int Value
    { get; set; }

    public List<LevelTwo> Childs
    { get; private set; }

    public LevelOne()
    {
        Value = (++_i);
        Childs = new List<LevelTwo>();
    }

}

public class LevelTwo : AActivation
{
    static int _i = 100;

    public int Value
    { get; set; }

    public LevelTwo()
    {
        Value = (++_i);
    }
}
```

**Objective is** serialize the given object tree in XML-file **excluded** from serialization objects whose property IsActivated equal false.

```
public class Serializer
{
    public static void Serialize<T>(T serializableObject , string path)
        where T: AActivation , new()
    {
        using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            XmlSerializer writer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            writer.Serialize(sw , serializableObject);
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var random = new Random();


        Root r = new Root();

        for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
        {
            var levelOne = new LevelOne() { IsActivated = random.Next(2) > 0};
            r.Childs.Add(levelOne);

            for(int j = 0 ; j < 5 ; j++)
            {
                var levelTwo = new LevelTwo() { IsActivated = random.Next(2) > 0};
                levelOne.Childs.Add(levelTwo);
            }
        }

        string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory , Path.GetRandomFileName() + ".xml");
        Serializer.Serialize(r , path);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Now I see several solutions:

1. Inherit for all classes [IXmlSerializable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface. But I don't want to interfere in the process of serialization as a serious way. And I need to change only the writing behavior, but also have to restore the reading behavior. After all, have to restore the default behavior, only one line of code.
   `if(obj.IsActivated == false) return;`
2. Create your own [XmlWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This lower level of XML model and again I don't want to interfere in its construction.

I hope there is a simple solution to my problem, that will not be so much to intervene in the process of serialization.

Comment: I would favor 1 over 2 since you are looking for special serialization and not special XML writing.

Comment: You might want to consider doing this in two passes. First do a normal serialize and then run it through a XSLT that only keeps what you want.